# Display Data from two Tables - Select two Tables at a time from a Database

Tags: mysql, sql

how do select two different tables at a time ?

**1st Table (table name "table1")**

```
capacity   comment

1.0        low
1.7        low  
7.2        average
9.9        fine
10.0       great
```

**2nd Table (table name "table2")**

```
c1     c2     c3   c4

1.0     CC    AS   DD
1.7     AD    AC   PD
10.0    AW    AS   AD
```

**if the input is 1.0 it should show**

```
capacity comment c2   c3   c4    
1.0       LOW    CC   AS   PD
```

**UPDATE**

```
    select a.capacity,a.comment, b.c1,b.c2,b.c3 from table1 a inner join table2 b on a.capacity=b.capacity WHERE a.capacity= $name

  $rs = mysql_query( $sql ) or die('Database Error: ' . mysql_error());


    $num = mysql_num_rows( $rs );

    if($num >= 1 ){
        echo "";
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $rs )){
    echo "<table>
        <tr>
            <th align='left' valign='middle'>Capacity</th>
            <td align='left' valign='middle'>$row[capacity]</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th align='left' valign='middle'>C2</th>
            <td align='left' valign='middle'>$row[c2]</td>
            </tr>               
        </table>";
     }
```

i have expected result like (in frontend)

```
| CAPACITY | 1.0|
|      C2  | CC |
```

but it is showing in doubt

i have expected result like (in frontend)

```
| CAPACITY | 1.0|
|      C2  | CC |

| CAPACITY | 1.0|
|      C2  | CC |
```

Comment: `SELECT ... FROM table1 JOIN table2 on table1.Column1 = table2.c1` read about joins in sql, what did you try yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query

```
select a.capacity, a.comment, b.c2, b.c3, b.c4 from 
tbl1 a 
inner join 
tbl2 b
on a.capacity=b.c1
WHERE a.capacity=1
```

### **[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/00e9e/2)**:

```
| CAPACITY | COMMENT | C1 | C2 | C3 | C4 |
------------------------------------------
|        1 |     low |  1 | CC | AS | DD |
```

Comment: what are a.* and b.* in this ? i didn't get this :( and it didn't worked for me

Comment: a.* will return all columns from a which alias to the table. Check the edit I have added proper column names.

Comment: @mehezad ok. i have a same coloumn in name in both tables (table name is **o3**. when displaying that row, if i use this  `$row[o3]` which row will display ? what should use there to display both ? any thing like `$row[a.03]` and `$row[b.03]` . am using php to display then in frontend

Comment: If you try displaying columns having same column name then only one will displayed and if you wish both should be displayed give `alias` to the column ex `SELECT a.ID AS aId, b.ID AS bId ..........`. hope this helps

Comment: Check this fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/96dcf/2. It has both type of query and it is always a good practice to write individual column names instead of using *.

Comment: but when i am displaing them in output, it is showing me two tables. 2 result tables. :(

Comment: I'm not getting what you are saying can post the query and result..

Comment: thanks. i have updated the question. kindly please check it ones. if possible. can you give me your skype/fb id. i will show it to you in screen share personally. thanks a lot. if you have any problem in this, please excuse me and solve my problem here. thank you!

Comment: You have shown your desired output but for actual output you have written `in doubt`, I'm not getting it.  Anyways while fetching values from array you have to use quotes like this `$row["capacity"]`. in your code you have not mentioned quotes and here http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php quotes  are used. Alternatively you can change your query to return only needed results `select a.capacity, b.c2 from table1 a inner join table2 b on a.capacity=b.capacity WHERE a.capacity= $name` and  [continue in next comment]

Comment: [continue] then you can use directly index while fetching records such as `$row[0]` and `$row[1]` but this is not a good practice to follow. Hope this helps..

Answer (score 1):

You only need a join in sql.

Like this.

```
select a.*, b.C2, b.C3, b.C4 
from table1 a join table2 b
on a.capacity=b.c1
WHERE a.capacity=1.0
```

[SQL code](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6edb8/4/0)